# Convert doc to html with style

Tags: html, xhtml, html-parsing, apache-poi, doc

I'm facing style issue while converting **.doc** files to **html** texts using **Apache POI**'s **HWPFDocument** class. Another problem is that it converts style tags too like this:

```
.b1{white-space-collapsing:preserve;} .b2{margin: 1.1798611in 1.1798611in 1.1798611in 1.1798611in;} .s1{font-weight:bold;color:black;} .s2{color:black;} .s3{font-style:italic;color:black;} .p1{text-align:center;hyphenate:none;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12pt;} .p2{text-align:justify;hyphenate:none;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12pt;} .p3{text-align:end;hyphenate:none;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12pt;}

Main Title
```

Here's my code:

```
HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(multipartFile.getInputStream());

WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
out.close();

String html = new String(out.toByteArray());
```

All I need is getting .doc file's content into HTML text format properly.

Comment: Any answer for this talha?

Comment: unfortunately no, not yet @KamranShahid